# Where is the best place to store your Smarty template cache files?

Tags: linux, apache, smarty

I'm considering either

```
/tmp
```

or

```
/var/cache
```

or

```
some folder in your code
```

I like /temp more, because if it grows too much, the system will usually take care of it, and it's universally writeable so probably more portable code.

But at the other hand I will have to store files in a folder within any of these, so making a folder and checking if it exists has to be done on /tmp, not on /var/cache, since /var/cache is not likely to get removed by linux or any other sort of common software.

What do you think? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches to storing smarty cache and, apparently, no best-case scenario i.e. the matter being more a matter of preference.

I can only say that I have witnessed hundreds of projects where Smarty cache was stored in the project's relative folders (for example /projects/cache/compiled/) for a number of reasons:

- Full control of the application's cache
- Ability to share the same cache amongst several servers
- No need to re-create the cache after the system has tidied the /tmp folder

Moreover, we see compiled templates residing inside memcache more and more each day.

Comment: I'm doing that as well, however the only problem we have is that the cached template files are bothering the version control that we use, we need to exclude it for commits and all that which is a pain in the neck, but I guess like you said there is no perfect solution